# CryptDecrypt result is table of NULL on Windows 8, on Windows 7 not

Tags: c++, windows, encryption, c++builder-5

I am trying to decrypt a RSA encrypted string using CryptApi function CryptDecrypt. 
Code works on Windows 7 64, but on Windows 8.1 64 CryptDecrypt in decrypted buffer returns table of \0 characters.
There is no error, CryptDecrypt does not return 0, GetLastError() is 0.

I tried using different CSP available in Windows, but it didn't change anything.

Does anyone can explain to me this behaviour?

Comment: What returned `0`? If [`CryptDecrypt()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379913(v=vs.85).aspx) returns `0` it means the function **failed** and you need to check `GetLastError()` for why.

Comment: GetLastError return 0, CryptDecrypt doesn't. Corrected question.

Comment: Do you have any code? Why can't we see it? An SSCCE is what is needed here.